# WinMain redefinition

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm just starting out in C++, and I'm running into an error I can't fix.

Here's all my code so far (can't even get hello world to work):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
               LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
                   MessageBox(NULL, L"Hello World!",
                       L"Hello World!",
                       MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
                   return 0;
}
```

But that gives this error when I try to run it:

> Test.cpp(11): error C2373: 'WinMain' : redefinition; different type modifiers
>            C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\winbase.h(2588) : see declaration of 'WinMain'

When I look at the declaration of WinMain, I see that there is an "__in" before each of the parameters. I tried adding that, but had no luck. I also tried replacing WINAPI with CALLBACK, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Try building with the `stdafx.h` include commented out - there may be some macro in there causing problems. What version of VS are you using? Can you post the build log?

Comment: It is LPWSTR, not LPSTR.

Comment: @HansPassant according to the docs, LPSTR is correct - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Try using `INT WinMain(...){...}` instead of `int WINAPI WinMain(...){...}`

Comment: @Michael Burr, I tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Also, I'm using VC++ 2010 express. When I tried to do the "INT WinMain," I got a link error for "unresolved external symbol _main"

Comment: Now that's interesting. I wouldn't expect that changing from int to INT caused that. Did you maybe change other settings in the meantime? Like changing the project type from Windows to console?

Comment: *"I'm just starting out in C++"* - Maybe you are perfectly aware of this, but just to be sure, you're not writing a plain C++ program, but a Win32 application (which may not be the best starting point when you're really just starting to learn C++).

Comment: I've been doing console apps since september, and java for the past few years. I know the languages aren't all that similar, but I think I should be able to start on Win32 apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple solution is to

**Use a standard `main` function**.

Like this:

```
#undef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#incude <windows.h>

int main()
{
    MessageBox(
        0,
        L"Hello World!",
        L"Hello World!",
        MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND
        );
}
```

Now your only problem is to build it as a GUI subsystem application using Microsoft's toolset, which is a bit more than retarded in this respect (the GNU toolchain does not have such a problem).

For that, with Microsoft's `link`, use this linker option (in addition to selecting the GUI subsystem): `/entry:mainCRTStartup`.

Note that you can put that option in an environment variable called `LINK`.

Happy coding! :-)

Comment: You can also tell the visual studio to compile a console application, that will automatically switch to main() as entry point. Concerning the defining/undefining of the UNICODE macro, that's also easier to achieve by setting the charset option in the general tab of the project settings.

Comment: @doomster: i'm pretty sure the OP does not want a console window. concerning the "easier" for the choice of macro set (UNICODE), no that's a pretty bad idea. code should stand on its own so that it can easily be moved or copied between projects, or built with other tools, not being dependend on details specified in some version-specific Visual Studio config file. Besides, it's absolutely not easier to click your way around in the visual studio project config, than to type two short lines at the top of the file.

Comment: The more typical linker option to use is to set `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`.

Comment: Just curious: What does the `L` in the beginning mean?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf But isn't the point of the WinMain function to provide the handles to instances of your program, so you can do stuff like prevent more than one instance from being open, and use command-line options? The options can be accomplished with a standard main function, but how would I accomplish the former?

Comment: @David: it is part of the literal's syntax, denoting wide characters, i.e. the `wchar_t` type.

Comment: @EnvisionRed: no, the `WinMain` function has never had any *technical* point, not even in 16-bit Windows. it does provide a main module handle, but you can more easily get that from `GetModuleHandle( nullptr )` rather than pass it around everywhere or storing it in a global. Ditto for the other `WinMain` arguments, including the `nCmdShow`: they serve absolutely no useful purpose, they make nothing easier.

Comment: @jamesdlin: the `/subsystem` option is not "more typical": it's a *different* option. it selects the Windows subsystem. the `/entry` option selects the entry point. those are independent choices. … oh, I see. **FIXED** that i forgot to clarify that! thanks!

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I meant that normally you can specify `/SUBSYTEM:WINDOWS` and provide a `main` function instead of `WinMain` and not need to manually specify `/entry`.

Comment: @jamesdlin: yes you can do that with the GNU toolchain. The Microsoft linker, however, is not very happy with it. It then (flagrantly ignoring the C++ standard) complains about a missing `WinMain`. So, better tell it explicitly to conform to the standard.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because, although it seems a bit hacky, it's the only thing that got my program working.

Comment: @EnvisonRed: regarding the `nCmdShow` argument, you didn't ask about it, but just for completeness: you don't even need to obtain it from somewhere, because if you use it for a first window creation *it's ignored*, and the value that you would get from, uh, whatever startup parameters function is called, is used automatically. i would guess that this was done because a great many programs failed to pass that value on. but anyway, the upshot is that none of the `WinMain` arguments are practically useful...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Hm, you're right.  I was talking about the Microsoft toolchain, but I must have misremembered.  Maybe I was thinking of using `editbin.exe` to change the `SUBSYSTEM` type afterward.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm trying to use "ShowWindow(Hwnd, nCmdShow)" and I don't know where to get nCmdShow in this scenario. You said it's ignored in initial window creation, so does that mean it doesn't matter what I put there?

Answer (score 1):

WinMain is a C function, therefore you need to wrap it with `extern "C"`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

extern "C"
{

    int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, 
               LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
    {
                   MessageBox(NULL, L"Hello World!",
                       L"Hello World!",
                       MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
                   return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used WinMain on C++ with VS2017 but I re-factorized lot of code and now It doesn't work. I don't know what I have done.